# Can't pass a Test Execution result to a variable in Robo Framework

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

I am posting the results of automated tests to an offline forum. It would be nice to include PASS/FAIL in the forum post title but I'm having some difficulties retrieving the ${TEST STATUS} value - (obviously a hard-coded value works fine) .

I've defined the following in common-variables.robot as:

```
${FORUM_TEST_RESULT}....${TEST STATUS}
```

then on publish-results.robot

```
Input Text....//*[@id="title"]....${FORUM_TEST_RESULT}
```

The error I get is: variable ${FORUM_TEST_RESULT} not found

I can see here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface that ${TEST STATUS} can only be used as part of Teardown.

I'm not sure how to collect the value of ${TEST STATUS} in the context of my RF script.

e.g the very last thing my script does is post to a forum:

```
Input Text....//*[@id="title"]....${FORUM_TEST_RESULT}
```

but before that I obviously need to populate ${FORUM_TEST_RESULT} with the value of ${TEST STATUS) which you can only get on Teardown? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The error I am dealing with is: variable ${FORUM_TEST_RESULT} not found, not the one above.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

`Input Text` is a keyword of `Selenium2Library` that types the given text into the text field of a web page. You need to start a browser session first and open the right page an then possibly wait for the element to become visible, for example like this:

```
Open Browser    [URL of your site]
Wait Until Element Is Visible    //*[@id="title"]
Input Text    //*[@id="title"]     ${FORUM_TEST_RESULT}
```

If you want to *retrieve* a text from a page (as your coment suggests) then you need to use the keyword `Get Text` which returns the text of the element identified by locator.

```
Get Text    locator
```

Comment: Thank you but I think you have misunderstood my question. I cannot retrieve the value  ${TEST STATUS}  (Automatic variable) value. At the end of the test the final stage is posting a result on the forum and I want to get this value.

Comment: then maybe you should edit your question in order to clarify. You are using Selenium2Library  and get an exception. I explained why this exception occurs and how to avoid it. If you cannot run a browser for any reason then Selenium2Library is the wrong tool to use.

Comment: It works perfectly hard-coded, so I don't think its anything to do with browser sessions of element visibility.

Comment: Really? What does the error message in your question tell us? **the error I get is: ElementNotVisible Exception: Message: element not visible**

Comment: Ok, I added your code and now this is problematic error occurred which was my original issue: variable ${FORUM_TEST_RESULT} not found. I will update the this post.

Comment: Have you declared your varaible file in your test case file?